# Android table layout last row smaller

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, tablelayout, tablerow

I would like to have a tablellayout with 3 rows and 4 columns.

The first two rows are ok but the last one is far too small then the others.

I tried it with a 5.5 screen size phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 2), where the rows are almost the same height, but on a 9.6 inch tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab E), the last row is very small. What am I doing wrong?

I have also attached my Layout file and a screenshot with the actual layout.

**My code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/domestic"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_start">

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <!-- Row with 4 columns -->
            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <!--Kutya-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnDog"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3sp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_elements"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:src="@drawable/dog"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin|bold"
                        android:text="@string/dog"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--Macska-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnCat"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3sp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_elements"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:src="@drawable/cat2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin|bold"
                        android:text="@string/cat"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--Diszno-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnPig"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_elements"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:src="@drawable/pig"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin|bold"
                        android:text="@string/pig"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--Tyuk-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnChicken"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_elements"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:src="@drawable/chicken"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin|bold"
                        android:text="@string/chicken"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
           ....
           4 times
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: 9.6 inch tablet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I figured it out that all images should have the same height, and then all rows have the same height. It's strange because I would have expected that by setting the tablerow's weight the inner content would automatically resize itself.